# Prototype into jquery

Tags: jquery, prototype

How does one go about changing an existing prototype function into a jquery one?

ie.

```
MainWindow = function()
{
    this.activeUser = "";    
    this.name = "";
}
```

And the call to bindAll

```
MainWindow.prototype.bindAll = function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a jQuery plugin...

```
(function($) {

   $.fn.mainWindow = function() {
      ...
   }

})(jQuery);
```

and then use it like:

```
$('#thingy').mainWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

The common method is to use an anonymous function in the context of jQuery, such as:

```
// anonymous function that is executed within the jQuery context
// to preserve reference in case of $.noConflict
(function($){
    // $ is now short for jQuery
    // $.fn is short for jQuery.prototype

    // if you want $.myCustomFunction
    $.extend({
        myCustomFunction: function(arg){
            $('#test').append($('<p>').text('myCustomFunction: '+arg));
        }
    });

    // or if you want $('...').myCustomFunction()
    $.fn.extend({
        myCustomFunction: function(arg){
            $.myCustomFunction(arg + ' [from selector]');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/Cfsb2/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm using your suggestion to extend.

How would i go about calling the bindAll function.

I've tried $.MainWindow = bindAll() but to no avail.

Comment: @GregS7: assuming bindAll is a method off of MainWindow, `$.MainWindow.bindAll()`